# visual studio publishing typescript files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, publishing

It would appear that Visual Studio does not publish .ts files by default but does publish the .map files when using Web Deploy.  I found an article which says I should add the following to the .csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="AddTsToContent" AfterTargets="CompileTypeScript" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="@(TypeScriptCompile)" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

This did in fact seem to work as immediately after adding this the .ts files did in fact publish.  Unfortunately I had to immediately remove the setting because after adding this none of typescript project includes worked anymore and the project wouldn't compile because all of a sudden all the path for references were wrong.

```
/// <reference path="../../sharedlibv2/sharedlibv2/ts/fb.core.ts" />
```

needed to be

```
/// <reference path="../../../../sharedlibv2/sharedlibv2/ts/fb.core.ts" />
```

in order to reference correctly. This path is completely invalid as it goes backward beyond the root of my hard drive, so clearly something is messed up.  There are many hundreds of shared project files affected here and the reference this setting seems to require is not going to fly with others using these projects.  I am guessing but haven't proven it that there will be other problems show up anyway.

I am using Visual Studio 15.5.7.  Is there any other method of getting Visual Studio to publish .ts files via Web Deploy ?